# How to make the validation that only accepts lower case 'a-z' and number '0-9'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have my app and it has username column.
For user input, I'd like to make this column with validation.

username has to contain only the characters below

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a format validator:

```
validates :username, format: { with: /\A[a-z0-9]+\z/ }
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_validations_callbacks.html